# msxml3.dll Access Denied

Tags: vbscript, msxml3

I have the following code:

```vb
Function filejson(json) 
  Dim objStream, strData 
  Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream") 
  objStream.CharSet = "utf-8" 
  objStream.Open 
  objStream.LoadFromFile(json) 
  strData = objStream.ReadText() 
  filejson = strData 
End Function 
Function http2json(url) 
  Set http = CreateObject("Microsoft.XmlHttp") 
  http.open "GET", url, FALSE
  http.send ""                                   '<------- Line 13
  http2json=http.responseText 
End Function 
Function str2json(json,value) 
  Set scriptControl = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl") 
  scriptControl.Language = "JScript" 
  scriptControl.AddCode("x="& json & ";") 
  str2json= scriptControl.Eval( "x"& value ) 
End Function 
Function get_json_from_file(json,value) 
  get_json_from_file=str2json(filejson(json),value) 
End Function 
Function get_json_from_http(url,value) 
  get_json_from_http=str2json(http2json(url),value) 
End Function 
Function save_json_from_http(url,loc) 
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
  fullpath = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(loc) 
  Dim objStream, strData 
  Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream") 
  objStream.CharSet = "utf-8" 
  objStream.Open 
  objStream.WriteText http2json(url) 
  objStream.SaveToFile fullpath, 2 
  save_json_from_http=fullpath 
End Function
Wscript.Echo save_json_from_http("http://api.themoviedb.org/3/authentication/session/new?api_key=#####some_api_key_example#####&request_token=#####some_default_request_token######&_ctime_json_=1372670635.164760555","tmdb\temp\_tmdb_sock_w.164519518.2109")
```

When I run this code, I get the following error.

[image: VBs msxml3.dll Error]

If I remove `&request_token=#####some_default_request_token######` it works just fine.

I also tried this: I added again the `request_token`, and I just typed a random character in it, for example, `rexfuest_token`, and strangely it worked. It seems there's a wrong parse in msxml3.dll. with request_token word.

Ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try with a more recent version:

```
Set http = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHttp.6.0")
```

It could also be an issue with your Internet security settings (see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2008/01/15/msxml3-dll-access-is-denied-msxml4-dll-access-is-denied.aspx)). Open the *Internet Options* applet in the Control Panel, select the zone for the website (probably "Trusted sites") in the *Security* tab and click *Custom level…*.

[image: Internet Options Security tab]

In the section *Miscellaneous* set *Access data sources across domains* to **Enabled**.

[image: Security Settings - Miscellaneous]

Comment: Same story access denied msxml6.dll

Comment: Internet Options > Security tab > Custom level did the trick for me.

Comment: Same with me: access denied to msxml6.dll until I changed Custom level setting, then it worked.

Answer (score 24):

This problem could be related to the security issues in Windows. The best way to fix it is to replace `Microsoft.XmlHttp`/`MSXML2.XMLHTTP` with `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP`.

I see the topic is almost 2 years old and most likely the topic starter has solved is issue. I have experienced the same issue couple hours ago and google provided me several links. There are some of them:

1. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1abda1ce-e23c-4d0e-bccd-a323aa7f2ea5/access-is-denied-while-using-microsoftxmlhttp-to-get-a-url-link-in-vbscript-help?forum=xmlandnetfx
2. https://support.webafrica.co.za/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/615/41/msxml3dll-error-80070005-access-is-denied---loading-xml-file
3. http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Scripting/ASP/Q_27305017.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. I was trying to consume REST services from VFP using Microsoft.XmlHttp/MSXML2.XMLHTTP. POST and DELETE worked OK but PUT wouldn't; using MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP was the solution, it works like a charm now.

Answer (score 2):

Also can change URL from http to https. Me helps

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to add the URL in trusted sites.

Internet explorer browser > Tools > Internet options > Security > Trusted sites > Sites > Add the URL under "Add this website to the zone: " and click add and save.

[image]