# Moving Batch file to different Computer

Tags: batch-file

So I have a batch file that works well on my computer either using `%userprofile%` or writing out the full path. The issue I have is when I move this batch file to a new computer it gives me either a curl error or no error at all.

This line:

```
del "%userprofile%\Ayla_Data\AylaDatapoints\*.*?"
```

works fine on the other computer. This line:

```
curl -H "Authorization: auth_token %$token%" https://ads-dev.example.com/apiv1/number/!$Unit!/props.xml>%userprofile%\Ayla_Data\XMLFile.xml
```

Does not. All I did was put the folder `Ayla_Data` onto a usb and copied it to a different computer.

If I take out the second part of the command curl works fine:

```
curl -H "Authorization: auth_token %$token%" https://ads-dev.example.com/apiv1/number/!$Unit!/props.xml
```

I thought that maybe I didn't have the `userprofile` variable set but that hasn't helped. Is this a problem with the computer reading the `%` as a character instead of part of a variable? I'm not really sure what's going on. Any ideas?

Comment: First, put quotes around the path.  Second, does the full path exist?  Did you try creating the directory first?  E.g., `mkdir "%userprofile%\Ayla_Data"`?  What error prints out?

Comment: I think it exists. but I'll try to create it to see if that's the fix. I just tried logging out of myself and into another user with the same computer and I get `msxml3.dll:access denied` error. I'm trying to see if that's the problem. I'll try putting quotes around it to see if that helps as well. Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: @indiv thank you I appreciate the suggestions. Putting quotes and creating the directory doesn't seem to work. I still get `msxm13.dll: Access denied` error.

Comment: Right click the batch file and run as administrator.  See if the behaviour changes. The quotes are needed because the username can contain spaces etc `"%userprofile%\Ayla_Data\XMLFile.xml"`

Comment: Running it in admin helped but I also installed a newer version of `msxml3.dll` as per this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17401413/msxml3-dll-access-denied that made it work!

Comment: This has been answered. OP found their answer [HERE][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17401413/msxml3-dll-access-denied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching a little about this error I found that my specific problem had to do with `msxml13.dll` being wrongly installed on my computer and the other computer had a firewall up.

I used this question to help:

stackoverflow.com/questions/17401413/msxml3-dll-access-denied

In case it helps anyone else this problem can also occur if the path specified in VBscript or batch is wrong or placed into the wrong path.

```
usrProfile = WshS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%UserProfile%")

Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.Async = "False"
xmlDoc.Load (usrProfile & "\Ayla_Data\XMLFile.xml")
```