# How to download .exe file from web and run it with some script?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I need to create some script (maybe .bat/.vbs or something else) that will download and open the file on double-click.

**How can I do this?**

Example:
I double-click on file (run.bat) and it goes to the link:
http://download.teamviewer.com/download/TeamViewer_Setup_en.exe
download and install this file.

I've tried something like this:

```
Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", "http://download.teamviewer.com/download/TeamViewer_Setup_en.exe", 0 
oXMLHTTP.Send
Set oADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB" & ".Stream")
oADOStream.Mode = 3
oADOStream.Type = 1
oADOStream.Open
oADOStream.Write oXMLHTTP.responseBody
oADOStream.SaveToFile "C:\TeamViewer_Setup_en.exe", 2 
dim path, WshShell
path = "C:\"
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
WshShell.Run path & "TeamViewer_Setup_en.exe", ,true
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: How *exactly* did it "not work"?

Comment: It worked for me. If by "not work" you mean you're getting an "Access Denied" error, see @AnsgarWiechers's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17402920/2237785). Also, why the concatenation of string _literals_!? `("ADODB" & ".Stream"`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** : [How can I download a file with batch file without using any external tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28143160/how-can-i-download-a-file-with-batch-file-without-using-any-external-tools)
More detailed answer of how files can be downloaded from internet in windows.

Here are two ways.The first uses bitsadmin.exe and the second hybrid jscript.net/bat (should be saved as .bat).The .net way is faster according to my tests , but creates a small .exe file that is called.And the second is a "pure" batch script.

```
  @echo off
    setlocal

    call :download "http://download.teamviewer.com/download/TeamViewer_Setup_en.exe" teamv.exe
    teamv.exe
    exit /b %errorlevel%
    :download

    if "%2" equ "" (
        call :help
        exit /b 5
    )

    if "%1" equ "" (
        call :help
        exit /b 6
    )
    set url=%~1
    set file=%~2
    rem ----
    if "%~3" NEQ "" (
        set /A timeout=%~3
    ) else (
        set timeout=5
    )

    bitsadmin /cancel download >nul
    bitsadmin /create /download download >nul 
    call bitsadmin /addfile download "%url%" "%CD%\%file%" >nul
    bitsadmin /resume download >nul 
    bitsadmin /setproxysettings download AUTODETECT >nul

    set /a attempts=0
    :repeat
    set /a attempts +=1
    if "%attempts%" EQU "10" (
        echo TIMED OUT
        endlocal
        exit /b 1
    )
    bitsadmin /info download /verbose | find  "STATE: ERROR"  >nul 2>&1 && endlocal &&  bitsadmin /cancel download && echo SOME KIND OF ERROR && exit /b 2
    bitsadmin /info download /verbose | find  "STATE: SUSPENDED" >nul 2>&1 && endlocal &&  bitsadmin /cancel download &&echo FILE WAS NOT ADDED && exit /b 3
    bitsadmin /info download /verbose | find  "STATE: TRANSIENT_ERROR" >nul 2>&1 && endlocal &&  bitsadmin /cancel download &&echo TRANSIENT ERROR && exit /b 4
    bitsadmin /info download /verbose | find  "STATE: TRANSFERRED" >nul 2>&1 && goto :finishing 

    w32tm /stripchart /computer:localhost /period:1 /dataonly /samples:%timeout%  >nul 2>&1
    goto :repeat
    :finishing 
    bitsadmin /complete download >nul
    echo download finished
    endlocal
    goto :eof

    :help
    echo %~n0 url file [timeout]
    echo.
    echo  url - the source for download
    echo  file - file name in local directory where the file will be stored
    echo  timeout - number in seconds between each check if download is complete (attempts are 10)
    echo.
    goto :eof
```

**OR**

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /****** jscript comment ******

@echo off
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:::       compile the script    ::::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
setlocal
if exist simpledownloader.exe goto :skip_compilation

set "frm=%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\"
:: searching the latest installed .net framework
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%v in ('dir /b /s /a:d /o:-n "%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v*"') do (
    if exist "%%v\jsc.exe" (
        rem :: the javascript.net compiler
        set "jsc=%%~dpsnfxv\jsc.exe"
        goto :break_loop
    )
)
echo jsc.exe not found && exit /b 0
:break_loop


call %jsc% /nologo /out:"simpledownloader.exe" "%~dpsfnx0"
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:::       end of compilation    ::::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:skip_compilation

:: download the file


::
::::::::::
:: simpledownloader.exe "%%~1" "%%~2"

simpledownloader.exe  "http://download.teamviewer.com/download/TeamViewer_Setup_en.exe" teamv2.exe
teamv.exe

:: del /q simpledownloader.exe
::
::::::::
::

exit /b 0


****** end of jscript comment ******/

import System;
var arguments:String[] = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
var webClient:System.Net.WebClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
print("Downloading " + arguments[1] + " to " + arguments[2]);
try {
    webClient.DownloadFile(arguments[1], arguments[2]);
} catch (e) {

        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine("\n\nProblem with downloading " + arguments[1] + " to " + arguments[2] + "Check if the internet address is valid");
        Console.ResetColor();
        Environment.Exit(5);
}
```

Comment: I'm trying use the second way and it works fine, file downloads. But if i add in the end of bat file a line with run of the file then it didn't work. I also need to open the file. I've tried add start teamv2.exe after all code and in try{} after webClient.DownloadFile(arguments[1], arguments[2]);
it didn't work. Why?

Comment: @Bazinga everything after `****** end of jscript comment ******/` is a jscript code and not part of the actual .bat file.If you want something executed at the end of the script put it before the  `exit /b 0`